# Split values of a column in a data frame by specific tag and add them as extra row

Tags: string, r, split, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data frame

```
> df <- data.frame(var1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),            
                 var2 = c("test", "5 | 6", "X & Y", "M | N | O"))
> df
  var1          var2
1    A          test
2    B         5 | 6
3    C         X & Y
4    D     M | N | O
```

How can I split the values in `var2` by the `|` and the `&` operator and put them as separate rows into the `same data.frame`. The output should look like the following:

```
> df
  var1          var2
1    A          test
2    B             5
3    B             6
4    C             X
5    C             Y
6    D             M
7    D             N
8    D             O
```

I used `strsplit` and a for loop to achieve it. However, I think that this is not very well coded. Any ideas how to achieve this in a better R-way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
s <- strsplit(df[,2], " \\| | & ")
cbind(var1=rep(df[,1], sapply(s, length)), var2=unlist(s))
     var1 var2  
[1,] "A"  "test"
[2,] "B"  "5"  
[3,] "B"  "6"  
[4,] "C"  "X"  
[5,] "C"  "Y"  
[6,] "D"  "M"  
[7,] "D"  "N" 
[8,] "D"  "O"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "var2", "[|&]", "long", fixed = FALSE)[var2_new != ""]
#    var1 var2_new
# 1:    A     test
# 2:    B        5
# 3:    B        6
# 4:    C        X
# 5:    C        Y
# 6:    D        M
# 7:    D        N
# 8:    D        O
```

Comment: Hmm, can't you do `cSplit(df, "var2", " [|&] ", "long", fixed=FALSE)`?

Comment: @RichardScriven, Did that work for you? Seems like it would need tweaking.

Comment: Yes, on my machine your answer errors but my comment works. Version 1.4.2.  When I remove the subset from the end of your call the columns are `var1` and `var2` still. I'll show you in chat