# Find specific tag in column of data frame and add tag in separate column to the same data frame

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I used R code from a user who answered my previous question (see here:  [Split values of a column in a data frame by specific tag and add them as extra row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517966/split-values-of-a-column-in-a-data-frame-by-specific-tag-and-add-them-as-extra-r))
to achieve the following:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),            

             var2 = c("test", "5 | 6", "X & Y", "M | N | O", "none"))

> df         
  var1          var2
1    A          test
2    B         5 | 6
3    C         X & Y
4    D     M | N | O
5    E          none


t1 <- c("", "|")[df$var1 %in% df$var1[grep("\\|", df$var2)]+1]

t2 <- c("", "&")[df$var1 %in% df$var1[grep("&", df$var2)]+1]

t1[which(t2 == "&")] <- "&"

df$var3 <- t1


> df
  var1          var2     var3
1    A          test     
2    B         5 | 6        |
3    C         X & Y        &
4    D     M | N | O        |
5    E          none
```

I was just wondering if there is a better way of doing it as I really want to improve the way I do my R coding. For me, this wasn't really a simple task to achieve but I am willing to learn :-)

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is something like `df$var3 = gsub("([a-zA-Z0-9 ])", "", df$var2)` but it is not exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is really this nicely organized, with proper spacing and so on, you can use `gsub` along with `substring`.

```
df$var3 = substring(gsub("([a-zA-Z0-9 ])", "", df$var2), 1, 1)
df
#   var1      var2 var3
# 1    A      test     
# 2    B     5 | 6    |
# 3    C     X & Y    &
# 4    D M | N | O    |
# 5    E      none
```

1. For your search pattern, look for all letters and numbers and spaces, and replace them with nothing.
2. Then, use `substring` (or `substr`) with `start` and `stop` as `1`.

## Update

A more general approach, assuming there might be different punctuation marks in `var2`, would be:

```
gsub("[^[:punct:]]", "", df$var2)
# [1] ""   "|"  "&"  "||" ""
```

Again, using `substr` would allow you to select only the first character in each string.

```
substr(gsub("[^[:punct:]]", "", df$var2), 1, 1)
# [1] ""  "|" "&" "|" ""
```

If you definitely only have those two separating characters, you can change the search pattern from `[^[:punct:]]` to `[^\\||\\&]`.

In the examples in this update, the `^` (within square brackets) means to match everything *but* these characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this instead :

```
t3 <- rep("",length(df$var1))
t3[which(grepl("&",df$var2))] <- "&"
t3[which(grepl("\\|",df$var2))] <- "|"
df$var3 <- t3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grepl("\\|",df$var2)
grepl("&",df$var2)
```

is the same as

```
df$var1 %in% df$var1[grep("\\|", df$var2)]
df$var1 %in% df$var1[grep("&", df$var2)]+1
```

so you can use for example

```
ifelse(grepl("\\|",df$var2),'|','')
ifelse(grepl("&",df$var2),'&','')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution which works great for me in only one line :-)

```
library(stringr)

df$var3 <- str_extract(df$var2, "\\||&")
```

However, I have to say that I do not care about the code adding 's to where no matches are found.

Thanks for all of your solutions though! Great work indeed!

Comment: If you look at the code for `str_extract`, you'll see that it does pretty much exactly the same thing that [I proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11521896/1270695) ... also in one line, BTW ;-)

Comment: yes, that is right! However, in your code you need to cover really everything (i mean special characters and normal characters) to be sure to only get | and & back whereas mine works on checking for those two directly. Your code is still pretty good though :-) Cheers!

Comment: Ah great. Sorry, I missed the Update section. Yes that would work as the only two special characters I match are | and &. Will have a closer look at that now.